# Настойка импорта. Не добавляет в репозиторий определенные типы файлов

Tags: linux, tortoise-svn

Cервер - CentOS 6.3. Использую svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486).

На клиенте - TortoiseSVN.

Репозиторий настроил, хук пост коммит тоже настроил, чтобы сайт сам обновлялся после любого коммита. В общем, нарадоваться не мог, когда все получилось. Но я экспериментировал всего с 2-мя пхп файлами, просто чтобы проверить, что все работает, изменяется. Но как дошло дело до переноса в репозиторий рабочего проекта, тут и начались проблемы. Нажимаю импорт - указываю адрес репозитория - адрес рабочей папки - ругается на файлы с точкой вначале (.htaccess), на изображения png, jpg, на стили css, на обычные текстовые файлы, созданные в нот паде.

Как это победить? Ума не приложу. Подробной инфы не нашел по этому вопросу, вроде, как пишут, нужно настроить майм типы, свойства, автосвойства и еще что-то. Как это сделать? Да, и где настраивать нужно - на сервере или на клиенте?

Вот пример ошибок, которые выскакивают:

```
PUT request on
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/98805f3a-4cc2-2e4e-b645-ba46a775c35f/trunk/css/404.css'
 failed: 405 Not Allowed

Access to
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/c98e9267-b3b9-c84c-a9e7-bba7c5cfc105/trunk/.htaccess'
 forbidden
Additional errors:
PUT of
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/c98e9267-b3b9-c84c-a9e7-bba7c5cfc105/trunk/.htaccess':
 403 Forbidden

D:\Projects\testing.com\trunk\WTD_A.txt
PUT request on
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/439abfde-16ee-fc41-82b0-b8e7f8a94193/trunk/WTD_A.txt'
 failed: 405 Not Allowed

D:\Projects\testing.com\trunk\audio\10.wav
PUT request on
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/55bdd757-2249-8d41-bebe-d0c17b004afe/trunk/audio/10.wav'
 failed: 405 Not Allowed

D:\Projects\testing.com\trunk\backups\dump_19.09.2014_interfaces.zip
PUT request on
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/04f6820b-0694-7343-815f-594723b8a54c/trunk/backups/dump_19.09.2014_interfaces.zip'
 failed: 405 Not Allowed

D:\Projects\testing.com\trunk\captcher\f7be421d688aeb1a0274eadfe8f837b7.png
PUT request on
 '/svn/testing/!svn/wrk/b3cacb45-9800-4148-83d2-3f0859231719/trunk/captcher/f7be421d688aeb1a0274eadfe8f837b7.png'
 failed: 405 Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

ошибка *405 Not Allowed* вызвана, скорее всего, тем, что такой файл уже существует.

вероятно, что-то напутано с ветками.